# Why is rails giving me an UnknownAttributeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I feel like I'm missing something, but I'm getting an error on my Rails app for something I'm not even mentioning. It's probably to do with the relations between the Request and Comment models. Here's the error:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in RequestController#comment
unknown attribute: request_id
```

And here's the relevant code;

```
# Making a comment on a request
def comment
    comment = @request.comments.create(text: params[:text]) # Error on this line
    comment.user = current_user
    comment.save
```

The code for request.rb:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
end
```

And for comment.rb:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_length_of :text, :minimum => 1, :maximum => 300
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :request
end
```

Comment: `belongs_to :request` signals to AR that it should expect a `request_id` column in the `comments` table.  Have you run your migrations?  Check the schema.rb to ensure this column is present.

Comment: please show `schema.rb`

Comment: Here's the schema.rb: http://pastebin.com/Lcj3WYyH

Comment: You're right, the relationship ids are missing but I did run db:migrate. Should I add them manually?

Comment: Sorry, @steakchaser I forgot to tag you.

Comment: The relationship is probably missing from your migration where you created the `comments` table.  If this is not in production, I would suggest first rolling back to before that migration (i.e. `rake db:migrate rollback STEP=[a number]`), then adding a `t.references :request` to the comments migration, then migrating back up.

Comment: Thanks @steakchaser, that fixed it. I must've added the associations after doing a migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship is probably missing from your migration where you created the comments table. If this is not in production, I would suggest first rolling back to before that migration (i.e. `rake db:migrate rollback STEP=[a number]`), then adding a `t.references :request` to the comments migration, then migrating back up.